# disable/hide script manager

Tags: c#, .net, scriptmanager

I am using scriptmanager on a mobile site but due to massive amount of data page gets from couple of script sources it loads slow on older phones. I have a class where I deduct phone capabilities and set page target. What I am after is to remove links to ScriptResource.axd or some other Ajax method to post retrieve data with partial update.

I have tried Controls.Remove.... but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This answer may hold the key to your problem:

[Disable ScriptManager on certain pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057905/disable-scriptmanager-on-certain-pages)