# Disable ScriptManager programmatically when ScriptManagerProxy controls are present

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

I've tried following this advice for disabling a ScriptManager programmatically, to no avail:
[Disable ScriptManager on certain pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057905/disable-scriptmanager-on-certain-pages)

**StandardScriptManager.ascx**:

```
<%@ control language="vb" autoeventwireup="false" codebehind="StandardScriptManager.ascx.vb" inherits="StandardScriptManager" %>
<h1>StandardScriptManager is visible</h1>
<asp:scriptmanager id="MyScriptManager" runat="server" enablepartialrendering="true" >
        <scripts>
            <asp:scriptreference path="/Standard/Core/Javascript/script1.js" />
            <!-- etc... -->
        </scripts>
</asp:scriptmanager>
```

**StandardScriptManager.ascx.vb**:

```
Partial Public Class StandardScriptManager
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Private _ScriptManager As ScriptManager

    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        If DisableAllScripts Then
            Me.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

When `DisableAllScripts` is true, the `<h1>` doesn't show up, but the scripts are still added to the page. I suspect this is because I have ScriptManagerProxy objects elsewhere on the page.

I've also tried `Me.Controls.Clear()` in `Page.Init`, but I get this

```
[InvalidOperationException: Page cannot be null. Please ensure that this operation is being performed in the context of an ASP.NET request.]
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.get_IPage() +372796
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPageInitComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnInitComplete(EventArgs e) +8699478
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +467
```

It's maddening that there's not a straightforward way to disable the ScriptManager; the control has no `Enabled` property, and you can't set `ScriptManager.Visible=False`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I could not get this to work either but I found a solution today.

If you are using .Net 4.0 you can use the new AjaxFrameworkMode property and set it to Disabled.

[ScriptManager.AjaxFrameworkMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.ajaxframeworkmode.aspx)

> Use the AjaxFrameworkMode property to enable all Microsoft Ajax script
>   files, to disable all Microsoft Ajax script files, or to explicitly
>   include individual script files.

ScriptManager1.AjaxFrameworkMode = AjaxFrameworkMode.Disabled

Hope that helps someone who ends up here as I did..