# ASP.NET Ajax Accordion Control not working properly with ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptmanager

I've been reading SO for a while now, but that's the first time I post a question (first time I don't find the answer of what I'm looking for)

Here is my setup:

Master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Master.master.cs" Inherits="VatechWebsite.Master" %>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        ...
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="content" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Content page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Brand.aspx.cs" Inherits="VatechWebsite.Brand1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" runat="server">
    <asp:Accordion ID="CategoriesAccordion" runat="server"  HeaderCssClass="AccordionHeader">
            <HeaderTemplate><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CategoryName") %></HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="ProductList">Some text<br />supposed to be very large <br/></div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:Accordion>
<asp:Content/>
```

When I run this page, the accordion displays correctly, binds data correctly, and has the first pane expanded. The problem is, I cannot expand/collapse a pane. It seems that the javascript associated with this control is not running correctly. If I replace ScriptManager in the master page with a ToolkitScriptManager, the problem is solved; but I don't want to do that because I have other pages that need the ScriptManager. 
I read that the ScriptManager should be adequate for running asp ajax controls, so why is it not working in this case?

Comment: Have you tried just replacing ScriptManager with ToolkitScriptManager at the Master Page level?  That's what I've always done and have never had issues with content working with ScriptManager but not ToolkitScriptManager.

Comment: As I mentioned, replacing ScriptManager with ToolkitScriptManager solves the problem, but it creates other problems: basically the js files imported in the master page "won't work" with ToolkitScriptManager, but that's another question

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with one ScriptManager for some pages, and ToolKitScriptManager for another, there are ways to use the same master page on all your pages, and use different ScriptManager on different pages.

This answer details a few approaches, one approach will disable `Master.ShowScriptManager = false;` on PageLoad.

[Disable ScriptManager on certain pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057905/disable-scriptmanager-on-certain-pages)

Another suggests having different ScriptManagers on for different ContentPlaceHolders, which also works.

Hope this helps!